# How to make a grid of buttons with good proportions

Tags: android, android-gridview

I need to create a grid with 4 square (or rectangle) with the same proportions

- The 4 squares must have the same size, and take all the space
- The margin must be the same everywhere
- There will always be only these 4 squares

I did it with a gridview but i can't manage the margins easily. How can i acheive this ?

Here is the gridView :

```
android:id="@+id/activity_home_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_home_search"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/margin_large"
```

Here are the cells

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_blue" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cell_grid_allzic_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cell_grid_allzic_label"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use GridLayout instead of GridView.

Comment: When you have fix grid item then GridLayout is more convenient.

Comment: Well i'm struggling with the margins :/

Comment: can you please post your code ? then try to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55894/discussion-between-haresh-and-yume117).